# Swift 5 and Storyboard UITableViewDelegate not showing Custom or any other style content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm new in Swift language and Xcode and I'm trying to make a `UITableview` Embedded in View Controller with a class `HomeViewController` which is one of four tabs and tried to use drag and drop with Storyboard and tried all available Cell styles and tried to do it programmatically with a custom Cell but when I run always see Empty Table view

Someone help me please and thanks details are below

`HomeViewController.swift`

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    //MARK: Properties

    var products = [Product]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Load the sample data.
         loadSampleProducts()

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return products.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
        let cellIdentifier = "ProductTableViewCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? HomeTableItem  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of HomeTableItem.")
        }

        // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
        let product = products[indexPath.row]

        cell.itemTitle.text = product.productName
        cell.itemDesc.text = product.productDesc
        cell.itemImage.image = product.productImage

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }

    //MARK: Private Methods


    private func loadSampleProducts() {
        let photo1 = UIImage(named: "nikeShoes")
        let photo2 = UIImage(named: "nikeShoes")
        let photo3 = UIImage(named: "nikeShoes")

        guard let product1 = Product(productName: "Caprese Salad", productImage: photo1, productDesc: "Make sure the names of the images in your project match the names you write in this code.") else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate products")
        }

        guard let product2 = Product(productName: "Chicken and Potatoes", productImage: photo2, productDesc: "After creating the Meal objects, add them to the meals array using this code:") else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate products")
        }

        guard let product3 = Product(productName: "Pasta with Meatballs", productImage: photo3, productDesc: "Find the viewDidLoad() method. The template implementation looks like this:") else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate products")
        }

        products += [product1, product2, product3]

    }


}
```

`HomeTableItem.swift`

```
class HomeTableItem: UITableViewCell {


    // MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var itemTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemDesc: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

And here what I'm seeing after running the project

[image: Simulator Screen]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var productTableView: UITableView!

var products: [Product] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadSampleProducts()
}

private func loadSampleProducts() {
    let photo1 = "photo1"
    let photo2 = "photo2"
    let photo3 = "photo3"

    let product1 = Product(name: "Caprese Salad", image: photo1, desc: "Make sure the names of the images in your project match the names you write in this code.")

    let product2 = Product(name: "Chicken and Potatoes", image: photo2, desc: "After creating the Meal objects, add them to the meals array using this code:")

    let product3 = Product(name: "Pasta with Meatballs", image: photo3, desc: "Find the viewDidLoad() method. The template implementation looks like this:")

    products += [product1, product2, product3]
    productTableView.reloadData()

}

}

extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return products.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ButtonTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonTableViewCell

    let product = products[indexPath.row]

    cell.itemTitle.text = product.productName
    cell.itemDesc.text = product.productDesc
    cell.itemImage.image = product.productImage
    return cell
}

}
```

In storyBoard -> UITableView -> set delegate and dataSource..

Comment: Done sir thanks should set the delegate and dataSource connection in the storyboard by dragging dataSource and delegate into ViewController but can I ask for an explanation if `tableView.delegate = self` has the same function why I'm getting an error if I set the delegate and dataSource in `HomeViewController.swift`

Comment: Yes both are same. Some prefer storyboard & some prefers coding more. I prefer storyboard but in some cases like using collectionView inside table view, setting delegate thru storyboard doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

add

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         tableView.delegate = self
         tableView.datasource = self
        // Load the sample data.
         loadSampleProducts()

    }
```

at the end

```
func loadSampleProducts()
{
   //......
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

> update

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ProductTableViewCell")
}
```

Comment: Getting error after `delegate` and `dataSource` with output `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier ProductTableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Comment: add this and try again `override func viewDidLoad(){
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ProductTableViewCell")
}`

Comment: getting error if you mean i will add this line in `HomeViewController viewDidLoad()` output `The dequeued cell is not an instance of HomeTableItem.: file /Users/ahmedels/Desktop/xCode Works/SBApp/SBApp/ViewControllers/HomeViewController.swift, line 49` means in cell declaration !

Comment: change the line `guard let cell .....` for `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HomeTableItem ` and do you use storyboard for use a custom cell? you don't forget add class of custom cell to cell on table view (https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/custom_cell_class.png)

Comment: It has HomeTableItem class in storyboard and after removing guard and declare it directly same issue `let cell` is `nil`